# Using native Windows or OSX dialog from Qt 5.3 application

Tags: qt, qt5.3

I have an application running on Windows and OSX that I am considering porting to Qt.

Currently the application uses the native certificate detail dialogs [CryptUIDlgViewCertificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380289(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows and [SFCertificatePanel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/SecurityInterfaceFramework/Classes/SFCertificatePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on OSX.

Is there any way I can these native dialogs from a Qt application or will I need to roll my own Qt certificate details dialog?

I found [QWinHost](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/qwinhost.html) as a possible solution for Windows, but this seems to have been dropped from Qt5.

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue mixing and matching Qt with platform specific APIs as needed.  Are you running into a specific problem?

Comment: Original question posted while we are still in the planning phase. I did just run a quick experiment with CryptUIDlgViewCertificate on Windows and that seemed to work as expected when launched from the Qt app. Hopefully OSX will follow suite.